# Filter Java stream if specific object is a null

Tags: java, stream

I have the object FastFood. In ArrayList there are 10 hotdogs.

```
public class FastFood {
    ArrayList<Hotdog> hotdogs;
    boolean isTasty;
}

public class Hotdog {
    String name;
    Ingredients ingredients;
}
```

For 9 hotdogs all data is filled.
For 1 hotdog, the object Ingredients is null.

How can I modify below metod to have only these hotdogs, which have filled Ingredients? (I would like to see 9 hotdogs).

```
public List<Hotdog> convert(Fastfood fastfood) {
      List<Hotdog> hotdogs = fastfood.getHotdogs().stream()
                    .map(this::convertToHotdog)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: To remove objects with `null` property you need to apply `filter()`, or if you don't need them at all you can use `fastfood.getHotdogs().removeIf(hd -> hd.getIngredients() == null);` instead of creating a stream. What does the method `convertToHotdog` is meant to do? `getHotdogs()` returns a list of `Hotdog`s and result is also `List<Hotdog>`, so what is happening in between?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on comments & question, it looks like `convertToHotdog` might be something to do with internal conversion of  `Hotdog`  which is not shared as a part of question. In that case, below might be useful:

```
List<Hotdog> hotdogs = fastfood.getHotdogs().stream()
                    .filter(t->Objects.nonNull(t.getIngredients()))
                    .map(this::convertToHotdog)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have list of hotdog objects, you can use `filter()` method, like this:

```
List<Hotdog> hotdogs = fastfood.getHotdogs().stream()
                    .filter(hotdog->hotdog.getIngredients()!=null)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

NOTE: I'm assuming that you have getter method for ingredients field in Hotdog class which is called `getIngredients()`

Comment: is there any way to do it before .map() method?

Comment: I don't understand why do you need this method convertToHotdog? You already have list of hotdogs. This fastfood.getHotdogs().stream() will give you stream of hotdog objects.

Comment: it's received from external service in a crazy way and need advanced mapping :D this is why I'm trying to do this before .map() if this is possible

Comment: But this fastfood.getHotdogs() will give you list of hotdogs, rights?

Comment: yes but I'm getting nullpointer in .map()

Comment: What does than this method convertToHotdog do? Judging by it's name, I would say that it converts the object into a hotdog class object. But there is no need to do that, since after this line of code : fastfood.getHotdogs() you already have list of hotdog objects